# GRUB2: how to remember grub last choice

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm currently trying out various distros so when I boot up my laptop I have several OS to choose from. Usually, all those distros install `grub2` and locate themselves at the top of the list so they're the default ones to boot up after the installation is complete.

But Manjaro did something different. It installed some version of `grub2` that would *remember* which distro I booted last time and kept booting that one (upon restart) until I selected another one (and then it would boot that one and so on).

Did I imagine this? Does Manjaro actually do that? If so, how can I install **that version** of `grub` to my system? Cheers.

---

This is my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

and this is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: I followed the directions in that question (mainly added those two lines to my `grub`) but it did not work. The top distro boots up upon restarting even though I had chosen another one previously.

Comment: I followed the directions in the accepted answer. I edited `/etc/default/grub` and I changed the line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and added the line `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` which wan't there. Then I `sudo update-grub`. Rebooted and chose a distro to boot, different from the top one. Rebooted again and the top (not the one I had chosen before) distro was chosen by default and booted.

Comment: I updated my question with what's inside those two files. What is the change I should do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7804/discussion-between-don-crissti-and-gabriel)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the [GRUB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html):

> ‘GRUB_DEFAULT’
>
> .................
>
> If you set this to ‘saved’, then the default menu entry will be that saved by ‘GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT’, grub-set-default, or grub-reboot.

---

> ‘GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT’
>
> If this option is set to ‘true’, then, when an entry is selected, save it as a new default entry for use by future runs of GRUB. This is only useful if ‘GRUB_DEFAULT=saved’; it is a separate option because ‘GRUB_DEFAULT=saved’ is useful without this option, in conjunction with grub-set-default or grub-reboot. Unset by default. This option relies on the environment block, which may not be available in all situations (see Environment block).

You must add:

`GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`

and

`GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`

to your `/etc/default/grub`. Also, if you are using custom menu files like `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` you must add the option

`savedefault`

to the menuentry/menuentries in that file. After that update GRUB:

`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

or

`update-grub`

If you have several distros installed, make sure you are configuring and updating the **active** GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this using Arch as a VirtualBox guest. The issue turned out to be my use of LVM.

Again, from the [GRUB Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Environment-block):

> 13.2 The GRUB environment block
>
> It is often useful to be able to remember a small amount of information from one boot to the next. For example, you might want to set the default menu entry based on what was selected the last time. GRUB deliberately does not implement support for writing files in order to minimise the possibility of the boot loader being responsible for file system corruption, so a GRUB configuration file cannot just create a file in the ordinary way. However, GRUB provides an “environment block” which can be used to save a small amount of state.
>
> The environment block is a preallocated 1024-byte file, which normally lives in /boot/grub/grubenv (although you should not assume this). At boot time, the load_env command (see load_env) loads environment variables from it, and the save_env (see save_env) command saves environment variables to it. From a running system, the grub-editenv utility can be used to edit the environment block.
>
> For safety reasons, this storage is only available **when installed on a plain disk (no LVM or RAID)**, using a non-checksumming filesystem (no ZFS), and using BIOS or EFI functions (no ATA, USB or IEEE1275).
>
> grub-mkconfig uses this facility to implement ‘GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT’ (see Simple configuration).